# Typescript syntax

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, typescript-generics

I'm new to TypeScript, and working one of my company's repos that uses it heavily.  (We're building a React/Redux app.)  I'm familiar with the basic concept of TypeScript Generics, but a particular bit of syntax is befuddling.  Here's an example of the code in question (it's in a reducer):

```
interface EntityState<Entity> {
  entity?: Entity;
  status: ApiStatus; // enum
}

interface FieldSummary {
    dataType?: string;
    // other properties...
}

function singleField(state: EntityState<FieldSummary> = defaultEntityState, 
  action: ActionTypes) {...}
```

Would someone be able to explain what `EntityState<FieldSummary>` is doing?  If further details are needed just let me know.

Comment: It's an instantiation of a generic type `EntityState<FieldSummary>` would be equivalent with the type  `{ entity?: FieldSummary; status: ApiStatus; }` .. Not sure what is  not clear ..

Comment: <GenericType> is any type that you defined that you can pass in later. I documented React Typescript syntax here - http://syntax.wiki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an example of a generic type argument.

```
interface EntityState<Entity> {
  entity?: Entity;
  status: ApiStatus;
}
```

The interface will contain an optional `entity?` of a type to be defined later. For now, it has been called `Entity`.

When you use this interface, you supply the type, thus:

```
const stringEntity: EntityState<string>;
```

The property `stringEntity.entity` will either be a `string` or `undefined` (given it is optional).

```
const numEntity: EntityState<number>;
```

The property `numEntity.entity` will either be a `number` or `undefined`.

And so on. The type argument you supply when you use the interface can be any type that satisfies any constraints - in your case, the type parameter is unconstrained. It means you can re-use an interface because the type is defined later.

Comment: So, to be clear, `EntityState<FieldSummary>` means that the `state` argument should have the `status` property from the `EntityState` interface, and optionally have an `entity` property that is whatever type `FieldSummary` is?

Comment: @jdmac - yes. `EntityState<FieldSummary>` results in `myEntity.entity` being of type `null | FieldSummary`.

Comment: @AndyJ - you're quite right. I made the mistake I thought you had! I've corrected it.

Comment: @Fenton No worries ... JavaScript is pretty messed up, and trying to keep all the different things like null vs undefined, and "truthiness" straight in my own head is hard! Take a well earned upvote.